# react-redux: understanding communication between Provider and representational components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I have difficulties understanding how the global store should be dispatched with actions from my react components. I'm very new to the whole concept and I don't get my component to re-render on dispatch(). I invested deeply and found that although the reducer returns the updated global state the values are not mapped back to the component props. But a proper function (mapStateToProps) is defined.

Minimal example: [Please have a look at this plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/zuoeii8KxSVXp3iO2Mmx/) (or minimal example code below).

Explanation:
I have a component `Controls` with a method `switchActivities`. The component is connected to the global store and my global state is available in the component props.

```
var PullFromStoreControls = function (state) {

  return {
    concrete: state.me.bool,
    nested:   state.me.nested.later
  }

}

var PushToStoreControls = function (dispatch) {
  return {
    switchFilter: function (type, value) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_VAL',
        value: value
      })
    }
  }
}

Controls = connect(
  PullFromStoreControls, 
  PushToStoreControls
)(Controls)
```

I wired the variable `state.me.bool` to *props.conrete* to avoid side-effects of a deep state tree. I also connected a dispatcher to update the global state via the reducer. However, if the dispatcher is invoked by 'switchActivities' the new value of the checkbox makes it up to the reducer correctly and then gets lost. The global state seems never updated correctly.

What am I missing?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="react@*" data-semver="15.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="redux@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.2.1/redux.js"></script>
  <script data-require="react-redux@*" data-semver="4.4.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js"></script>

  <!-- support for jsx on my localhost, on Plunkr jsx will be automatically transpiled to js -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/babel"  src="minimal.jsx"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="app"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

### minimal.jsx

```
 function d(x){
  console.log(x);
}

const AppState = {
  me: {
    bool: false,
    nested: {
      later: "I also want to change values deeper in the tree."
    }
  }
}

function reducer(state, action) {

  if (state === undefined) {
    return AppState;
  }

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'SET_VAL':
      state.me.bool = action.value;
      break;

  }

  console.log("The reducer returns the changed state");
  console.log(state);

  return state;

}

// create global store with initial configuration `AppState`
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, AppState);

// create provider and connect function not having webpack available
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect  = ReactRedux.connect;


class Controls extends React.Component {

  switchActivities() {

    console.log("------------------ clicked ------------------");

    console.log("set value from:");
    console.log(this.props.concrete);

    // inverse current state
    const state = !this.props.concrete;

    // output
    console.log("to:");
    console.log(state);

    // call dispatcher
    this.props.switchFilter("show_act", state);

  }

  render() {

    console.log("I would like to re-render if this.props.concrete has updated!");

    const switchActivities = <MapSwitch name="switch_act" label="Show something" checked={this.props.concrete} onChange = {() => this.switchActivities()} />;
    return <div id="map-controls">

      {switchActivities}

    </div>

  }

}

var PullFromStoreControls = function (state) {

  return {
    concrete: state.me.bool,
    nested:   state.me.nested.later
  }

}

var PushToStoreControls = function (dispatch) {
  return {
    switchFilter: function (type, value) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_VAL',
        value: value
      })
    }
  }
}

Controls = connect(PullFromStoreControls, PushToStoreControls)(Controls)


const MapSwitch = ({name, label, checked, onChange}) => (

  <label for={name}>{label}

    <input type="checkbox" className="switch" data-toggle="switch"
           name={name}
           onChange={onChange}
           checked={checked}
    />

  </label>

)


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Controls/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

## Solution (update)

It **is** a difference whether I alter the `state` object within the reducer and return that or if I create a new object and return that. Although both returned objects are the same the former is a reference while the latter is a real new variable. I learned that the hard way.

Good explanation: 
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.md

```
function reducer(state, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'SET_VAL':
      return {
        ...state,
        me : {
          ...state.me,
          bool: action.value
        }
      }
  }

  return state;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mutating `state`. The second principle of Redux is that the `state` should never be mutated directly - rather, your reducer is a *pure function* which should `return` a new state: https://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions

Your issue is here:

```
switch (action.type) {

    case 'SET_VAL':
      // you are attempting to mutate state.me.bool - this is an antipattern!
      state.me.bool = action.value;
      break;

}
```

Instead, write your reducer in a way that returns a new copy of `state`.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_VAL':
            return {
              ...state,
              me : {
                ...state.me,
                bool: action.value
             }
           };
         default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to copy each level of `state` for nested structures. I'm using the Object spread operator here, but Object.assign() with all work. Hope this helps!

Comment: I read this so many times "mutating state" but had no idea how to actually prevent this. In the docs `Remember to return new state objects, instead of mutating the previous state.` Thank you so much, Sir. 
Can you please write out your `...` I'm too stupid to get it...

Comment: Ok, `...` is a jsx syntax ;) But your notation gives me syntax errors.

Comment: `...` isn't specific to JSX. It's a feature of ES6: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html What is the error you're receiving? If you don't have ES6 support for Object spread, `...` will not work.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work thanks to you. But your code contains a syntax error. Please correct your answer slightly (see my update).

Comment: @agoldev I fixed the syntax. Mind flagging as correct if this worked for you?

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks again!